# HTTP 404 Hello World JSP outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

My hello world runs perfectly fine in eclipse as shown below :

[image]

In eclipse I have the location of tomcat pointing to the local instance as shown in the image below:

[image]

However, when I copied the `WebContent` folder from Eclipse folder structure and copied inside `webapps` folder of local instance, renamed it to `helloworldjsp` and tried to access the URL in the browser like the following :

http://local.xyz.com:8080/helloworld/hellowWorld.jsp

I get the following error :

[image]

All files and names are spelled correctly, and I am wondering why I am getting the same error?

Comment: what is error showing in console?

Comment: @Janny The above error(HTTP Status 404) that I am getting is after directly using the url on the browser. Could you tell me which console you are referring to as it's outside eclipse?

Comment: If you named the directory `helloworldjsp`, then your URL should be `http://local.xyz.com:8080/helloworldjsp/hellowWorld.jsp`.

Comment: @Andreas My bad, that was the problem. I started my tomcat using startup.bat and it ran. There was URL problem as well.One question. Does starting tomcat in debug mode using catalina jpda start command is considered as starting tomcat server ?

Comment: Yes, it just allows connecting a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have some name issue. please use the below URL and let me know the result.

http://local.xyz.com:8080/HelloWorldJSP/hellowWorld.jsp